# I edit functions.php but can't access to

Tags: php, wordpress, function, parsing

I was doing editing to function.php file and when I refreshed it, it gives me error and now I can't get into wp-admin it is giving me same error whenever I am trying to get into my website. My website is `www.studentsbaithak.com`

I am understanding the error but there is no such `'<'` sign in the file and it keep on giving the same error. I can't log in to my wp-admin dashboard.

This is the error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected `'<'` in
`/home2/students/public_html/wp-content/themes/flex-lite/functions.php
on line 179`
```

Comment: Do you have access of Cpanel or FTP ?

Comment: yes @DineshBhojvani

Comment: okay great then login in cpanel or connect with FTP you can change in your file code. after that you are again able to access that file from wp-admin

Comment: i am in cpanel right now where should i go now? @Dineshbhojvani

Comment: from cpanel navigate to public_html or html folder in that your site folder, then wp-content folder. wp-content->theme->function.php  theme folder should be your active theme

Comment: i am in the file manager right now let me try that.

Comment: okay I hope now you are able to do that.

Comment: Thank you so much Love for Stack Over flow and for you too @DineshBhojvani

Comment: Fell happy to help you.

Comment: have one more questionI am using MAMP on mac 
When i am clicking on my website link its showing me a white page that's it no error nothing. How to fix this problem I Need help :(

this url is just a white page 

http://localhost:8888/Studentscart/

Comment: this website is in WP or any other framework ?

Comment: this is also wp @DineshBhojvani

Comment: Let's chat in group i have invited you in group

Comment: i didn't see any invitation here ? @DineshBhojvani where is it

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136591/wp-discussion

Comment: i don't have much reputation here so i can't get access to chat it wont let me do it @DineshBhojvani

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit function.php using FTP (use filezilla) or through cpanel.

Comment: I have Filezilla but how should i connect to the server. what will be my HOST:      USERNAME:    PASSWORD:  and PORT:

Comment: do you have cpanel access?

Answer (score 0):

For edit file you can you either use cpanel or FTP.
If you are in cpanel  then find public_html or html folder in that your side folder. Now from site folder Wp-content->theme->functions.php here theme folder means it should be your active theme folder. there you can edit your functions.php file after that you are able to login again in your wp-admin.  Hope this will helps you.